Absolutely Summing Operators
Currently, I am reading the paper Bounds on Oscillatory Integral Operators Based on Multilinear Estimates by Bourgain and Guth. In the appendix, they proved a version of 'epsilon removal lemma', i.e.,if
$\|\hat{f}||_{L^{1}(d\sigma,S)} \leq C(p,\epsilon) R^{\epsilon} \|f\|_{L^{p}(B_R)}, \forall p \leq p_0, \epsilon > 0,R \gg 1, f \in L^p \tag{1}$
then
$\|\hat{f}||_{L^{1}(d\sigma,S)}\leq C(p)\|f\|_{L^{p}}, \forall p<p_0, f \in L^p \tag{2}$
where $S$ is a smooth, compact hyper-surface with positive definite second fundamental form, $\sigma$ is its surface measure, and $B_R$ is the ball centered at the origin with radius $R$.
Let $T$ be the dual operator of $\hat{f}|_{S}$. If (1) holds, then
$\|Tf||_{L^{q}(B_R)}\leq C(q,\epsilon) R^{\epsilon} \|f\|_{L^{\infty}(d\sigma,S)}, \forall q \geq q_0, \epsilon > 0,R \gg 1, f \in L^q(d\sigma,S) \tag{3}$
where $q_0$ is defined by $p_{0}^{-1}+q_{0}^{-1}=1$.
Now we fix $q$, $\epsilon$, and $R$, then $T:L^{\infty}(d\sigma,S) \rightarrow L^q(B_R)$ is bounded. On page 61, the authors claimed that, from the 'theory of absolutely summary operators', for any $r>q>2$, there is a probability measure $\mu$ on $S$ such that
$\|Tf||_{L^{q}(B_R)}\leq C(q,r,\epsilon) R^{\epsilon} \|f\|_{L^{r}(d\mu,S)}, \forall f \in L^r(d\mu,S) \tag{4}$
I have read some materials about 'absolutely summary operators'(such as Absolutely Summing Operators by Diestel, Jarchow, and Tonge), but I still don't know how the authors deduced this (My advisor also doesn't know). I emailed one of the authors, but he didn't answer my question in detail.
Is someone familiar with this?

The statement of this type is similar to the factorization theory in Banach spaces.  Maybe you can have a look on the Fernando Albiac & Nigel J. Kalton's book Topics in Banach spaces, 2nd edition, GTM 233. In Chapter 7, Theorem 7.1.2 and Theorem 7.1.9 maybe are related to your questions. Also, see Chapter 8, like Theorem 8.1.6.
I'm not familiar with these topics (Bourgain-Guth paper & the book mentioned above). But I hope these are helpful.
